# Hide routing values coming from action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use one page for showing two different texts based on the action the request coming from, if this request comes directly from the `Index` it shows some welcome text, and if it comes from the `Create` form it shows some other text:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? ticketSent)
{
    if (ticketSent == true)
        ViewBag.IfcText = "done";
    else
        ViewBag.IfcText = "hello";
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TicketNumber,OwnerName,Email,LaptopModelNumber,Subject,Description,ComplainDate")] Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ticketSent = true });
    }

    return View(ticket);
}
```

but when the request comes from the `Create` action the Url contains the query string, `http://localhost:54401/?ticketSent=True`, thus if the user refreshed the browser or even navigate to it any time he gets the same page indicating that the form sent successfully, I want to ensure it's being shown after he creates the form only without the query string.

This is the view:

```
@{if (ViewBag.IfcText == "hello")
    {
        <h2>Encountering a problem? We are here to help</h2>
        <h3>
            @Html.ActionLink("Contact our Support Team", "Create")
        </h3>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.IfcText == "done")
    {
        @:<h2>We received it, we will be in contact with you in 24 hrs.</h2>
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/

Comment: use tempdata to store the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use TempData to store the flag. It will only be available on the redirect from the previous request, which is what you wanted.

Check out this article to get a better understanding

[When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/)

The concept still applies for recent versions of MVC

```
const string ticketSentKey = "ticketSent";

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ticketSent = false;

    if(TempData.ContainsKey(ticketSentKey) && TempData[ticketSentKey] is bool) 
        ticketSent = (bool)TempData[ticketSentKey];

    if (ticketSent == true)
        ViewBag.IfcText = "done";
    else
        ViewBag.IfcText = "hello";
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TicketNumber,OwnerName,Email,LaptopModelNumber,Subject,Description,ComplainDate")] Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData[ticketSentKey] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(ticket);
}
```